# Pass in string to reusable php function

Tags: php, wordpress

I don't use php very much, so - my actual knowledge is centered around `require()` etc - for templates - and when needed, WordPress loops.

In a current project, I had to use this block of code 10 times on a page.

```
<?php
    $commercialLoop = new WP_Query(
        array(
            'post_type' => 'project',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'project-type',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => 'commercial'
                )
            )
        )
    );
?>

<?php while ( $commercialLoop->have_posts() ) : $commercialLoop->the_post(); ?>

    <li class='project'>
        <a href='<?php the_permalink(); ?>'>
            <div class='image-w'>
                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                <?php } else { ?>
                    <img src='http://placehold.it/1600x800&text=No featured image yet' alt=''>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
            <h3 class='project-name'><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h3>
        </a>
    </li>

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

In JavaScript I would just pass a few strings into a function - and then I could use that. In this case, the only thing that changes for each loop is `commercialLoop` and the `commercial'  - and I think that is all that changes... So, really just one string is all that I would need to pass in for each different category, 'residencial', 'housing', 'details' etc... I would expect I could do something like:

`<?php getLoopThing('commercial'); ?>`

BUT - I must not know the right search terms to find direction.

HELP???

================================================

### This is what I ended up doing:

Created a partial : taxonomy-loop.php - replacing the string in question with `$taxonomyName`

```
<?php
    $taxonomyName = new WP_Query(
        array(
            'post_type' => 'project',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'project-type',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $taxonomyName
                )
            )
        )
    );
?>

<?php while ( $taxonomyName->have_posts() ) : $taxonomyName->the_post(); ?>

    <li class='project'>
        <a href='<?php the_permalink(); ?>'>
            <div class='image-w'>
                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                <?php } else { ?>
                    <img src='http://placehold.it/1600x800&text=No featured image yet' alt=''>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
            <h3 class='project-name'><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h3>
        </a>
    </li>

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

In function.php : build the function with the `$taxonomy-name` passed in.

```
function getTaxonomyLoop( $taxonomyName ) {

    // grab the partial (wherever your partial is located)
    return include('parts/taxonomy-loop.php');

}
```

Then, where I wanted it to appear:

```
<?php getTaxonomyLoop('commercial'); ?>
```

### See any gotchas?

Comment: I don't understand. What part of your code do you want to reuse and add a string to?

Comment: I want that entire block of code to live somewhere:  `/templates/includes/loop.php` - and then, in another template - to call it, `<?php include('/includes/loop.php', 'string-to-pass-in'); ?>` - or something like that.

Comment: Yeah. And what in your code should be 'string-to-pass-in'?

Comment: the 4 places it says 'commercial'  -  `${{commercial}}Loop` or `{{commercial}}`

Comment: But 3 out of 4 are just variables, so it doesn't make a difference. Only the actual string `'terms' => 'commercial'` makes a difference

Comment: Well, I was just concerned that given the large number of queries, they should each have their own name - and it would be free. : )

Comment: They are all isolated in the scope of your function. It doesn't matter.

Comment: That is excellent to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass arguments to functions like this:

```
function a($a) {
    return $a;
}
```

Or If you just want the complete code:

```
function getLoop($st){
return new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type' => 'project',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'project-type',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $st
            )
        )
    )
);
}
```

So now you can call:

```
$loop = getLoop('commercial');
```

Comment: It answers the title but not the question.

Comment: Well does it answer the question now @putvande

Comment: The complete function should likely include the output block.

Comment: Although I'd gladly write that there are 2 reasons why I didn't:

Comment: 1: I think learning that you can return stuff from the func is nice

Comment: 2: I don't know where the hell $projectLoop1 comes from! Is it the same as $commercialLoop?

Comment: (forgot to amend that `$project1) ~ ( it IS '$commercialLoop' )

Comment: I actually like the way this was answered. The point is made clearly - as far as the function syntax.  ~ but ~ then do I `echo` that `$loop`  ?

Comment: @sheriffderek $loop is like $commercialLoop

Answer (score 0):

[`get_template_part`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part) is better suited for this sort of thing. It allows you to include the same template file multiple times, while still keeping your front-end code separate from your functions. It also allows your template code to be overwritten by a child theme.

In your theme directory, you would create a file containing your template code.

Then when you need to reference it you can just call `get_template_part` with the name of the file.

For example, if I were to create a file called `projects.php` in the theme root, I could include it in another template file like this:

```
get_template_part('projects');
```

You cannot pass parameters to your template file this way, but you can use globals or define functions for any additional data your template needs. For example:

```
global $taxonomyName;
$taxonomyName = 'commercial';
get_template_part('projects');
```

From there you could reference the taxonomy: `global $taxonomyName`.

Depending on how you are determining `$taxonomyName` you may be able to define a function to determine the taxonomy name without having to declare it global.

Comment: This sounds like half of an answer.

Comment: @sheriffderek Can you expand on that? All the OP needs to do is put the code he already has into a separate template file and then use `get_template_part` to include it.

Comment: What is the difference between this and say, `<?php require('thing.php'); ?>` or `<?php require('thing.php'); ?>` ? ? ?

Comment: ( I am the OP ) : )   - well, I just don't see how that helps me pass in the string that would make the whole thing useful.

Comment: @sheriffderek `get_template_part` references files within your theme. It also allows template parts to be overwritten by a child theme.

Comment: Well, so - it's really the same - but it's the 'WordPress' version. I'm never ever going to be using any child-themes for this project / or in general. I use as little WordPress as possible. I think it's just a neat/free admin panel.

Comment: @sheriffderek It's not the same: https://kovshenin.com/2013/get_template_part/ `get_template_part` will always reference files relative to your theme root. You don't have to worry about absolute paths or where the file is relative to where you are including it.

Comment: @sheriffderek Regardless of the differences between `get_template_part` and `require` my overall point is that `get_template_part` allows you to organize your front-end code and keep it separate from your functions.

Comment: I don't know what I'm missing, but `You cannot pass parameters to your template file this way` - isn't the answer to this question.

Comment: As I mentioned, you can use globals or define another function to determine the values you need in your template. Also, your current solution depends on the relative path to the file you are including. Look into `locate_template` to get an absolute path: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/locate_template

Comment: If there is a better way, and you want to explain how using globals etc could be super cool - and how that all works, that would be great. Otherwise, this is working great ( for my purposes ). This question was more general php than WordPress.

Comment: I use this 10+ places, with a different $string for each.

Comment: @sheriffderek How do you determine the string?

Comment: I'm hoping to determine it by typing it like described in the post. It would be one of many taxonomy terms.